# How to iterate DOM via jquery

Tags: jquery

**EDIT**: sorry i've rephrased my question

New to JQuery and need some assistance

I would like to iterate all li elements
and to delete the inner span element in one of the li's.

I do not know where the span is because the li is built dynamically and i cannot count on the id selector

```
    <ol id="selectable" class="ui-selectable">
        <li id="1_1_1" class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">1.1.1</li>
        <li id="1_1_2" class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">1.1.2</li>
        <li id="1_1_3" class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee ui-selected">1.1.3<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check"
            style="float: right; margin: 2px 7px 0 0;"></span></li>
        <li id="1_1_4" class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">1.1.4</li>
        <li id="1_1_5" class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">1.1.5</li>
    </ol>
```

How can this be done?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each -- "Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element."

Comment: You could even just use implicit iteration and do `$('#selectable li').attr('class','new');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** to delete the span, just do this:

```
$('#selectable li span').remove();
```

Be aware that it will remove all `span`'s within any `li` but from your example, there is only one.

Try out [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

```
$('#selectable li').addClass('foo');
$('#selectable li').removeClass('foo');
$('#selectable li').toggleClass('foo');
```

These are just a few ways to change the class of all `li`'s that match the selector.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery usually iterates internally:

```
$("#selectable li").toggleClass(...)
```

You can also use `.each` to iterate as some methods do *not* iterate such as `.html` and `.text` (I unfortunately don't know the list, though it would be very helpful).

Answer (score 0):

An another way to solve your problem is -
Using find function you can remove all the span tag wherever they are present in the selected element.

```
$('#selectable').find('span').remove();
```